# Delay inside/after subscribe in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, rxjs-observables

I'm setting `isUpdate` flag true in subscribe and I have to set it back to false after some delay so that I can show a quick popup

I have tried using `.pipe(delay(2000)).subscribe` However the entire callback is getting delayed

```
this.sp.myservice(data).subscribe(
data => {
this.isUpdate = true;
//something like this but not setTimeout
setTimeout(() => 
{
this.isUpdate = false
}, 2000) 
}
);
```

Expected Result: isUpdated should be false in some time

Comment: why not setTimeout()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are better ways to display a popup.

But to answer you, a clean way could be :

```
this.sp.myservice(data).pipe(
  tap(() => this.isUpdate = true),
  delay(5000),
).subscribe(() => this.isUpdate = false);
```

Live mode :

```js
rxjs.of('some mock value').pipe(
  rxjs.operators.tap(() => console.log('Wait 5 seconds')),
  rxjs.operators.delay(5000),
).subscribe(() => console.log('See ? I am delayed.'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.3/rxjs.umd.js"></script>
```

## Edit

for your request :

```
this.sp.myservice(data).pipe(
  tap(data => this.isUpdate = this.data && this.data.status && this.data.status.code === 0),
  delay(5000),
  catchError(err => throwError(err))
).subscribe(
  () => this.isUpdate = false,
  err => console.log('an error occured')
);
```

Live mode :

```js
rxjs.throwError('some error mock value').pipe(
  rxjs.operators.tap(() => console.log('Wait 5 seconds')),
  rxjs.operators.delay(5000),
  rxjs.operators.catchError(err => rxjs.throwError(err))
).subscribe(
  () => console.log('See ? I am delayed.'),
  err => console.log('an error occured')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.3/rxjs.umd.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for responding, However I want to display the popup only if the call is successful and if the data has the property I need

something like -  if (data && data.status && data.status.code == 0) { this.isUpdate = true}

is the data coming from service available in tap(data=>{})?

Comment: Subscribe is not getting called after tap :(

Comment: @AjayChandan well yes it is, you can see it live in the example ...